# keras.wrappers can't pickle _thread.lock objects when joblib has >= 2 jobs

Tags: python, scikit-learn, keras

I am trying to run a stacked regression when the n_jobs is 1 it runs fine however, whenever I set the n_jobs to 2 it crashes with the error below. I looked into similar issues but none actually solved my error.

The code:

```
from civismlext.stacking import StackedRegressor
from civismlext.nonnegative import NonNegativeLinearRegression

def create_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(150, activation='softmax', kernel_initializer='VarianceScaling', input_dim=456, name='HL1'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25, name="Dropout1"))
    model.add(Dense(150, kernel_initializer='VarianceScaling', activation='softmax', name='HL2'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25, name="Dropout2"))
    model.add(Dense(1, name='Output_Layer'))
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mae', metrics=['mae', 'mean_squared_error'])
    return model

mlp_model = KerasRegressor(build_fn=create_model, epochs=50, batch_size=75, validation_split=0.2, verbose=True)

super_learner = StackedRegressor([
    ('pipe_mlp', mlp_model),
    ('rf', rf),
    ('xgb', gb),
    ('meta', NonNegativeLinearRegression())
], cv=5, n_jobs=2, verbose=5)
```

the error:

```
MaybeEncodingError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-1d4b04377633> in <module>()
      1 # fitting the model
----> 2 super_learner.fit(X_train[:50], y_train[:50])

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/civismlext/stacking.py in fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    163         self.meta_estimator.fit(Xmeta, ymeta, **meta_params)
    164         # Now fit base estimators again, this time on full training set
--> 165         self._base_est_fit(X, y, **fit_params)
    166 
    167         return self

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/civismlext/stacking.py in _base_est_fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    220             n_jobs=self.n_jobs,
    221             verbose=self.verbose,
--> 222             pre_dispatch=self.pre_dispatch)(_jobs)
    223 
    224         for name, _ in self.estimator_list[:-1]:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
    787                 # consumption.
    788                 self._iterating = False
--> 789             self.retrieve()
    790             # Make sure that we get a last message telling us we are done
    791             elapsed_time = time.time() - self._start_time

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in retrieve(self)
    697             try:
    698                 if getattr(self._backend, 'supports_timeout', False):
--> 699                     self._output.extend(job.get(timeout=self.timeout))
    700                 else:
    701                     self._output.extend(job.get())

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py in get(self, timeout)
    642             return self._value
    643         else:
--> 644             raise self._value
    645 
    646     def _set(self, i, obj):

MaybeEncodingError: Error sending result: '[<keras.callbacks.History object at 0x7f93fe43c7b8>]'. Reason: 'TypeError("can't pickle _thread.lock objects",)'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the Keras scikit-learn wrappers don't exactly follow the scikit-learn API.

In scikit-learn, calling fit() on an estimator returns a fitted estimator.  In the Keras wrapper, the fit() call returns a callbacks.History object.